# Encoding in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to use eclipse encoding UTF-8, for polish characters. Unfortunately, I still have problem with encoding. My settings:

Window->Preferences->Debug
[image: Window->Preferences->Debug]

Window->Preferences->Workspace
[image: Window->Preferences->Workspace]

Window->Preferences->PHP Content Type
[image: Window->Preferences->PHP Content Type]

My php file:

[image: PHP file]

File proporties:

[image: File proporties]

End result:

[image: Result in browser]

Did I forget about something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eclipse browser probably just doesn't know which encoding to use, since you don't send any HTTP header specifying it.

Try sending the following HTTP header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Or use a real browser, and set the page encoding to UTF-8 explicitely.

Comment: In real browser (firefox) result is same. I will using this header. Thanks :)

Comment: In Firefox, go to the Display menu, choose "Character encoding", and select UTF-8.