# Android PHP POST accents paramters failed

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, diacritics

I am working in a project where we have an android application in the client side and the server side is being managed with PHP. The client should send informaton to the server and it should reply with a json containing the result. Everything is find till we use some special characters and I do not know how to solve the issue.

I ahve verified the Apache and PHP settings and both are working with UTF-8 as default charset.

The problems I am facing arer:

1. My PHP code is not able to manage by itself the values in the $_POST when they contain special characters. Should I decode it using urldecode() in PHP before I use it? The values are sent to the server with URLEncoder.econde(myvalue,"UTF-8"). See the code below.
2. My php code is returning an json object. If there is not special characters in the object everythig works but if it include some accent or similar then the object can not be managed.

Here is my code

Android side

```
public class HelperClassJSONDownload {
public HelperClassJSONDownload(){

}

// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
    // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
    // a string.
    public JSONObject downloadJSON (String myurl,List<NameValuePair> params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String json = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);//We need it to set parameters
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");



            //Writer w=new OutputStreamWriter(
            //      conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            //w.write(getQuery(params).toString());
            //w.flush();
            //w.close();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            //END SETTING PARAMETERS REQUEST



            // Starts the query 
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();

            switch (response){
                case 200:
                case 201:
                     inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                             (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,  "UTF-8"), 8);
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        json = sb.toString();
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                        return jsonObject;


                default:
                    return null;
                }


        } catch(IOException e){
            return null;
        } catch(JSONException e1){
            return null;
        }finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            } 
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method create the String we will pass with the parameters
     * @param params
     * @return the string used for  for the parameters
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

     }
```

This is the PHP code, the function generalCheckUserData() check some values and compare the information provided by the client. If the client submit some special character is not able to manage it. i.e. if we need to compare an á submitted with and a´ this function does not work if($_POST['values'] == á)
Also if the the json returned contain some special character it does not work.

I hope this information is enough

```
 public function __construct() {

    $this->response = array("tag" => $this->tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    if ($this->generalCheckUserData() && (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] == 'register')){
        $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password_new'], $_POST['user_password_repeat'],
                $_POST['user_first_name'], $_POST['user_last_name_1'], $_POST['user_last_name_2'], $_POST['user_telephone']
                ,$_POST['user_city'], $_POST['user_province'], $_POST['user_postal_code'], $_POST['user_country']);
    } else  {
        //we create an array where to storage the information returned to the client
        $this->response['error'] = 1;
        $this->response['error_type'] = 1;
        $this->response["error_msg"] = $this->mes;
        echo json_encode($this->response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

am not sure where this would help but from my general knowledge how about adding this connection property Accept-Encoding and set it to utf8 and in the PHP code in the connection area, set collation to UTF8

Comment: Hi Gamal, I would like to try your but please could you clarify "PHP code in the connection area, set collation to UTF8"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found that the problem was in Zend Studio settings. Please check this [Encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163005/encoding-in-eclipse) form more details.